# VSTO Outlook: Prevent user from resizing the custom task pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have a custom task pane placed at the top and I don't want user to resize its height, I want to keep the height always the same. Also when user tries to resize it, I would like to show a messagebox saying he/she is not permitted to do so (without hacks please). How can I achieve this?

Maybe doing something similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c8a633b8-f595-407f-a3d8-84ee10ee661e/how-to-set-a-minimum-height-for-a-custom-task-pane?forum=vsto)? The problem with this approach is that SendKeys.Send("{ESC}"); is closing window when you are in composing window.

Answer (score 1):

The [SendKeys.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method is the most easiest way of canceling the default action of resizing the pane. Instead, you may try to use Windows API functions such as `SetFocus` to shift the focus from resizing the pane. But there is no a ready-made solution for that out of the box.

As a possible workaround you may consider using [Advanced Outlook Form Regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-regions/index.php) instead. They allow managing the form in the way you need - hide/show, collapse, change the size and layout at runtime and etc.

Comment: Thanks again. Yep, that would be a possible workaround but I want to avoid using hacks or Windows API functions or third-party tools. The problem of sending 'ESC' keys using SendKeys.Send from the compose window, is that in compose window the 'ESC' key is a predefined key that closes the compose window. It is working fine on explorer window but not in the inspector (compose window).

Comment: I understood it from your post, but there is no trivial solution for that. Try playing with Windows API functions instead.

Comment: You say: "The SendKeys.Send method is the most easiest way of canceling the default action of resizing the pane". I have noticed that it is possible by sending one of the following keystrokes: {ESC}, {ENTER} and also by provoking a mouse click. Is there more keystrokes to cancel the resizing action using SendKeys.Send?

Comment: Sounds like a subject for a separate post there. Don't forget to mark the asnwers.